# Char Array Client.Print Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to read a QR code and send it the phpMyAdmin. I am using a DE2120 1D2D scanner and a UNO. The problem is with the printing , on the serial monitor looks like a string but in the php the each character from the code is printed on a new line, the idea is to client.print the entire code on the same row.

Code  bellow:

```
#include "SparkFun_DE2120_Arduino_Library.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <Ethernet.h>
#define BUFFER_LEN 40

    byte mac[] = {
    0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEE }; // 
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 22 );  //
    IPAddress gateway(10, 74, 0, 1); 
    IPAddress subnetMask(255, 255, 255, 192); 
    EthernetClient cliente;
    char server[] = "192.168.1.15"; // 

SoftwareSerial softSerial(3,2);
DE2120 scanner;

char scanBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];
String QR;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  softSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(scanner.begin(softSerial));

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      IPAddress newSubnet(255, 255, 255, 192);
      Ethernet.setSubnetMask(newSubnet);
      Serial.print("Ethernet.localIP: ");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
      Serial.print("Ethernet.gatewayIP:");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
      Serial.print("Ethernet.subnetMask:");
      Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
      
      if (cliente.connect(server, 8080)) {
        Serial.println("Connected to the server");}
}

void loop() {

  delay(200);

  if(scanner.readBarcode(scanBuffer, BUFFER_LEN)){
    Serial.println("QR availbale ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(scanBuffer); i++){   // Production Order
      Serial.print(scanBuffer[i]);
      QR = String(scanBuffer[i]);
      
      (cliente.connect(server, 8080));
        cliente.print("GET /ethernet/data_qr.php?");
        cliente.print("QR=");
        cliente.println(QR); // I tried also with client.print(QR) followed by client.println(), no chance.
        //client.println(); 
        cliente.stop();
     }
    Serial.println();
  }
  }
```

Serial monitor - QR is a String

[image]

Client.print result

[image]

I tried:

1. To convert the Char scanBuffer[i] to String and than printed. - 0 results
2. To store the serial monitor value ov scanBuffer[i] in a variable and the printed. - 0 results
3. Client.println / Client.print

What can I try , some ideas on order to client.print the QR content in the same row.

Thank you ! :D

Comment: The problem is because you're sending one character at a time. In fact, you create a brand new connections for each character. Why do you need the loop? Why not simply `cliente.println(scanBuffer)` (as well as `Serial.print(scanBuffer)`)?

Comment: The Serial.print(scanBuffer[i]) it's in the for loop, if I print only Scan.Buffer it shows nothing.

Comment: Well then just `print` with ***no*** `println`. The `ln` ending in `println` stands for *line* and means a newline is "printed" or sent.

Comment: And, don't do a new connection in the loop! Create *one* connection, print the request and the `QR=` part, then inside the loop *only* print the characters, without a newline. Then *after* the loop print a newline.

Comment: Yes, you had right, I can print only the scan Buffer without the for loop, now the problem is the board don't send anything to the sql, see the code bellow:

Comment: ```` void loop() {

  delay(200);

  if(scanner.readBarcode(scanBuffer, BUFFER_LEN)){
    Serial.print("QR availbale: ");
    Serial.println(scanBuffer);
    delay(1000);
    
        (cliente.connect(server, 8080));
        cliente.print("GET /ethernet/data_qr.php?");
        cliente.print("scanBuffer=");
        cliente.println(scanBuffer); 
        cliente.stop();
      
}
} ````

Comment: That seems like a very different issue, to be asked in a new question.

Comment: I tried with another char declared in the beginning of the program, and it works, I don't understand the difference between char scanBuffer and another char, with the same length.